# MKMapView won't add any annotations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

I have an MKMapView whose delegate is set in Interface Builder and which is a retained property (hooked up in Interface Builder as well) of its view controller. Yes, I am sure they are hooked up properly. I am trying to add annotations to the mapView, but mapView: viewForAnnotation: is not called, and after adding all of the annotations with [self.map addAnnotation:annot], printing the count of the mapView's annotations array yields zero. I have no idea what is causing this because my MapPerson object implements the MKAnnotation protocol with a readonly coordinate property. Here is my code for that business...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapPerson : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D _coo;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

And its implementation...

```
#import "MapPerson.h"

@implementation MapPerson

@synthesize coordinate=_coo;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)loc {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _coo = loc;
  }
  return self;
}
```

I am trying to create these annotations in a delegate method from a service class which fetches coordinates from a server to the view controller containing the mapView. I have tried moving that code to a helper method which I make sure to call on the main thread, but nothing happens.

```
- (void)refreshMap {
  for (MapPerson *p in mapPeople) {
    [self.map addAnnotation:p];
  }
  NSLog(@"Mapview has %i annotations.", self.map.annotations.count);
  // is always 1 for the user's location
}
```

I have Googled and SO's and looked at several different tutorials which do not differ from my code except in names. I put a breakpoint in mapView: viewForAnnotation:, and it is only called once for the user's location annotation. The count of mapPeople is 5. Their coordinates are being set correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: So everything in mapPeople checks out correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backend is using MongoDB which had reversed latitude/longitude. Thus, the annotations were added to a location that doesn't exist on the coordinate plane of the map. I feel like an idiot for not noticing this sooner. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Thanks for posting! My MapView was doing the same... I too had reversed the lat/lon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not getting warnings regarding MapPerson? I believe it says in the documentation that if you want to implement MKAnnotation you need to provide a title and subtitle as well.

Can you possibly provide the code where you populate mapPeople?

EDIT: Re-read documentation, it says title and subtitle are only expected of you if you plan on creating selectable annotations.

Comment: `MapPerson *p = [[MapPerson alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-150, 34)];
      
[people addObject:p];
      
[p release];
    
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapService:didFetchPeople:)]) {

      [delegate mapService:self didFetchPeople:people]; 
    
}`

Comment: Hmm... And your refreshMap function is being called correctly, but that does not trigger viewForAnotation?

Comment: No, it does not trigger viewForAnnotation. The mapView's delegate is set correctly, and viewForAnnotation is only triggered for the MKUserLocation annotation.

Comment: Are you updating the annotations anywhere other than refreshMap? So refreshMap is not being called either? Out of curiosity, what tutorial/walk through did you use to create what you have so far, if any?

Comment: I wrote this from my previous experience with map annotations. I've done this several times. It must be something small I've overlooked. RefreshMap is only called from the delegate method which is certainly being fired. I also tried doing this with another object that implements the MKAnnotation protocol, but nothing appeared with it either.

Comment: I'm not sure what it could be then... Perhaps some small flag isn't being set and keeping them from being displayed? At this point I'd just pull up an older project and do some comparisons. The code you posted for the bigger pieces looks fine, and especially if you've done this before its bound to just be some small issue.

Comment: Okay, so the backend is using MongoDB which reverses latitude/longitude. We didn't account for that, so the annotations were added to coordinates that do not exist on the coordinate plane of the map. I feel like an idiot for not noticing this sooner. Thanks for your help! I will self-answer when I'm able in two hours.

Comment: Ahhh, that would do it. Glad you got it figure out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your `p` or `people` is `nil`?

Comment: Neither is nil. I can print off each MapPerson's coordinates passed to the delegate from inside the delegate.